# Validar DatePicker Jquery BootstrapValidator

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy validando mi formulario con bootstrapValidator, la fecha solo se valida si la escribo, si la escojo desde el calendario no la válida. Si me pueden ayudar a validarla agradecería su ayuda. Utilizo el datepicker y bootstrapValidator.

CAMPO FORMULARIO:

```
 <form class="form registerForm" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <!--FECHA DE INICIO-->
           <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer ">
              <label class="control-label" for="text">FECHA DE INICIO:</label>
              <div class="input-group input-group-lg date datepicker3 container-calendar">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control puntero-i prohibido-no" name="newinputFechaIni" id="newFechaIni" value="" placeholder="CLIC AQUÍ Ó EN EL ICONO" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon manito-clic ">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="registrar-form" disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
</form>
```

Aqui estoy validando con boostrapValidator:

```
$('.registerForm').bootstrapValidator({
    live: 'enabled',
    fields: {
        newinputFechaIni: {
            validators: {
                date: {
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    message: 'ESTE VALOR NO COINCIDE CON UNA FECHA'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 10,
                    message: 'LA LONGITUD MÁXIMA ES DE 10 INCLUYENDO /'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[0-9-/]+$/,
                    message: 'LA FECHA SOLO PUEDE TENER NÚMEROS Y /'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Estoy inicializando datepicker que me pones ciertos valores por defecto del calendario:

```
$('.datepicker3').datepicker({

    container: '.container-calendar',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    language: 'es'

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537003/bootstrap-datepicker-and-bootstrap-validator#25644924), tienes que revalidar la fecha cuando el usuario realice cambios:

```
$('.datepicker3').on('changeDate show', function(e) {
        // Revalidar fecha
        $('.registerForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'newinputFechaIni');
});
```

Por cierto, ¿La clase *datepicker3* no debería estar especificada en el campo? o, en su defecto, iniciar *datePicker* con una clase o atributo específico del campo.

```
<form class="form registerForm" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <!--FECHA DE INICIO-->
           <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer ">
              <label class="control-label" for="text">FECHA DE INICIO:</label>
              <div class="input-group input-group-lg date container-calendar">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker3 puntero-i prohibido-no" name="newinputFechaIni" id="newFechaIni" value="" placeholder="CLIC AQUÍ Ó EN EL ICONO" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon manito-clic ">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="registrar-form" disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
</form>
```